# What does prefetch(-1) do in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I came across a data pipeline in Tensorflow that contained the statement:

```
training_dataset = training_dataset.prefetch(-1)
```

When I read the docs at [Tensorflow Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch), they specify that `prefetch(n)` means `n` elements are prefetched. I can't find what `n =-1` means. Is the entire dataset prefetched? Is nothing prefetched, but one can dynamically change that later? Something else?

Comment: The documentation you linked has the line *"If the value [`tf.data.AUTOTUNE`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data#AUTOTUNE) is used, then the buffer size is dynamically tuned."*, note that according to the link, `tf.data.AUTOTUNE == -1`. This isn't an answer, because I have no idea what a dynamically tuned buffer size means.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine - Thx. I feel silly for not chasing down that link. At least now I can speculate that the number of data elements prefetched is somehow connected to the amount of GPU memory available.